# Can't seem to run tesseract from command line despite adding PATH

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tesseract

I'm trying to add tesseract to be able to install pytesseract. 
I use Windows 7.

I add this path to my PATH environmental variable
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe`

From the command line if I run

`tesseract DMTX_screenshot.png out` 
        OR
`tesseract`

I'm getting

`tesseract is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

Here is a copy-paste of the a portion of my environmental variable:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe;C:\Users\Moondra\Anaconda_related\Anaconda\geckodriver.exe;`

Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So It seems there are two version for Windows, 4.00 and 3.05 -- 4.00 is still buggy.
I installed the 3.05 version and seems to work fine now.

Here is where I got the 3.05 version.

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

Comment: Update 20 June 2018 - version 4.00 runs after updating Windows 10 PATH to include location of Tesseract executable.

Answer (score 12):

The `PATH` variable should include directories only, not files, such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just tried, doesn't seem to make a difference. My webdriver (for seleium) has an exe. file  assigned as the value for the PATH variable and seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is the following you have to add `cd` first ...

Example:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR

C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR> tesseract --version
```

Answer (score 4):

After adding tesseract to PATH, make sure you restart your PC.
It only worked after the restart.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the folder to the Path under Windows (not sure with Win7):

**Control Panel > System and Security > System >**

**Advanced system settings > Advanced > Environment variables > PATH > New**

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem initially. Don't install tesseract via pip install tesseract.

Go to `https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki` and then download latest version for your computer and install that.

Then type `sysdm.cpl` and add the directory where tesseract.exe is present to env. variables.

for eg: `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR`

This solved it for me.

Comment: Type it WHERE?!

Answer (score 0):

Add `C:\msys64\mingw32\bin` to PATH variable in case you've installed it using pacman or msys2.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the solution for this problem and this works fine almost in all situations.

Step 1: download tesseract ocr from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
and install it.

Step 2: note the installation directory while installing and then add path to env variables.

Step 3: run "pip install pyteseract" in cmd or any terminal.

And you are done. Just be make sure to add same directory location of tesseract ocr in your code and add tesseract.exe after it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the location where you have installed `Tesseract-OCR` on the terminal and then type `tesseract -v`. This worked for me.

Comment: This isn't the solution xD